# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'app.articles' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `articles`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I was trying to create my db to laravel application but getting this error.
I was following this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIBST5vVq84&list=PLkceZXjwpt79ktt5N6ojNVAM-lzTWa1W5) tutorial.

I am unable to access my article database but i can access anything from User.php predefined model.

route.php

```
use App\article;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('article', function () {
    echo article::all();
});
```

article.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class article extends Model
{

}
```

```
in Connection.php line 673
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `articles`', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 629
at Connection->run('select * from `articles`', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 342
at Connection->select('select * from `articles`', array(), true) in Builder.php line 1508
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1494
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 596
at Builder->getModels(array('*')) in Builder.php line 303
at Builder->get(array('*')) in compiled.php line 10366
at Model::all() in routes.php line 20
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array()) in compiled.php line 8415
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8405
at Route->run(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8121
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3176
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13274
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11822
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13009
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12946
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9828
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8122
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8113
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8103
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2400
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3237
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9828
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2347
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2331
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_apps\App\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
1/2
PDOException in Connection.php line 333:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'app.articles' doesn't exist
in Connection.php line 333
at PDO->prepare('select * from `articles`') in Connection.php line 333
at Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(object(MySqlConnection), 'select * from `articles`', array()) in Connection.php line 666
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `articles`', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 629
at Connection->run('select * from `articles`', array(), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 342
at Connection->select('select * from `articles`', array(), true) in Builder.php line 1508
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1494
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 596
at Builder->getModels(array('*')) in Builder.php line 303
at Builder->get(array('*')) in compiled.php line 10366
at Model::all() in routes.php line 20
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array()) in compiled.php line 8415
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8405
at Route->run(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8121
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3176
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13274
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11822
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13009
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12946
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9828
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8122
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8113
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8103
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2400
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3237
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9838
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9828
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2347
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2331
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_apps\App\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: is there an 'articles' table in your db?

Comment: when you name your model 'Article' and you dont override $primaryKey, and $table, then Eloquent assumes the table to be 'articles' and primary key 'id'.

Comment: i have article table in database not articles, but its showing articles in error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model 'article.php' do this.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'article'; 
}
```

It will work for your 'article' table.

Comment: but i did'nt understand what was the problem?

Comment: The thing is, when you create a model and dont declare protected $table as a property, the Eloquent i.e. the Laravel's ORM sets the default value of table for that model in this way. If your model class is 'User' it will use the table 'users', which in your case you named it 'Article' so it looked for the table 'articles' in your db. Hope this answers your question brother.